# spring boot garbage collection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to limit the the maximum memory given to a `spring-boot` application and would like to check the garbage collection to see if what i have set is good or no .

I am using spring-actuator which do expose 4 properties

Sample 1

```
"gc.ps_scavenge.count": 84,
"gc.ps_scavenge.time": 1150,
"gc.ps_marksweep.count": 3,
"gc.ps_marksweep.time": 392
```

Sample 2

```
"gc.ps_scavenge.count": 804592,
"gc.ps_scavenge.time": 5361101,
"gc.ps_marksweep.count": 15923,
"gc.ps_marksweep.time": 2949279,
```

I could not find any guidelines on what to check and what is considered a good value also what exactly is the time value , is it accumulative or average ?

May be my question is well known but I have not experience is garbage collection monitoring and could not find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, spring boot actuator prints the time and count of all beans that implement the [GarbageCollectorMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html). The docs say that the time is "the approximate **accumulated collection elapsed time in milliseconds**".

What is a good value is dependent on your documentation, but from what I've read it is the *portion* of time spent collecting garbage that you should be concerned about. You should use the `uptime` metric to calculate the percentage of time.

Comment: Ok i see i did check one of the online systems found it is 0.24% which i think is good .

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the equivalent to these .time variables are with the spring boot 2 actuator, jvm.gc.pause TOTAL_TIME does not look like the same thing to me.